# Access denied to user ODBC, but trying to login as root

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, authentication, backup

I'm trying to do a backup of a MySQL database on Windows, but for some reason it's trying to log me in as `ODBC` instead of `root` - does anyone know why?

As you can see below the red line, I can login to MySQL no problem.

[image]

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA I get `root@localhost` for both.

Comment: Please run `SELECT user,host,password FROM mysql.user WHERE user='root';`. Questions: 1) How many root users are there ? 2) Do all root users have the exact same encrypted password ? 3) Do any of the root users have a blank host or blank password ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Here's [the output](http://i.imgur.com/SoL9Sar.png). I'm not sure if maybe you missed this part though - it's trying to authenticate me as the `ODBC` user, not `root`. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Question: Does the `my.ini` have a `[mysqldump]` section ? If so, please post it (hiding the password if supplied).

Comment: Try `mysqldump -uroot -p ideal_inv > ideal_inv.sql`. Does it prompt for a password ? Does it run when you give it the right password ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA No, there's no `[mysqldump]` section in my `my.ini`. Your suggestion above works! A step in the right direction, thanks!! I'm trying to script it though... does this help narrow down the issue?

Comment: Does your password contain a single quote, a double quote, a pipe, or a backslash ?

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA No, just alphanumeric - no special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I couldn't get `mysqldump` to login as `root`, it kept trying to login as `ODBC`. Instead I added this to my `my.ini` file and ran the command without user/password arguments:

```
[mysqldump]
user=root
password=XYZ
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to explicitly choose a host by doing one of the following:

```
mysqldump -hlocalhost -uroot -ppassword ideal_inv > ideal_inv.sql

mysqldump -h127.0.0.1 -uroot -ppassword ideal_inv > ideal_inv.sql
```